# How can I tell when I have all the collectibles in a level?

Tags: battleblock-theater

Many levels have five+ green gems to collect, but I don't know if I missed any when I'm near the exit. Are there any visual or audible indicators that I've collected all the gems in the level, or otherwise that I will have all the stamps (including the yarn ball and stopwatch) when I exit?

Answer (score 7):

When you get all of the gems in any level, the last gem you pick up will pick up will cause a green "explosion" effect.  There is a ball of yarn in every level.

Answer (score 0):

From what my experience is, no there is no "real" way to see whether or not you have all the collectibles.  But since you are shown a "results" page when you finish, which shows in boxes how many gems you collected (and ones you have missed), as well as placing a stamp of a cat if you find a ball of yarn.

Answer (score -1):

Most games uses the counter of gems(bonus items) in a level and they decrease as you collect them but if required amount is filled and user is collecting additional the additional will count as bonus pick ups ( because either they were harder to search )

Comment: This is a really speculative answer, and doesn't actually address the question directly.

Comment: I think you have played or take part in the game which sean has developed, please define how my answer is not to the point ?

Comment: You say "most games", but you don't say whether or not it applies to the game he mentioned, battleblock theater